# How to import android studio library project from github to eclipse stackover?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have some troubles when i try to add a android studio library to my eclipse project.

1. Create android project from existing code
2. Mark as library
3. Go to my project and adding the library.I see that the project(library) not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDggS.png)

Pls, any ideas?

Comment: It's not possible. We intend to add support for Gradle-based project in ADT but it's not currently possible. Why are you not going to use Android studio, ADT support for Eclipse stopped by google. Still you want you have to create Library project in Eclipse and add Code in respected folder and its required library or jars then add to original project . See this http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/importing-android-studio-projects-into-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. We intend to add support for Gradle-based project in ADT but it's not currently possible.

you have to Manually as shown bellow

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/importing-android-studio-projects-into-eclipse.html